# Please allow users to sort their favorites based on tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, bookmarks

It would be nice to be able to sort my favorites based on tag.  The reason why is that I have a lot of favorites saved over many different tags. If I'm looking for a favorite in "python", then I click "python" and see all my "python" favorites.

Does this seem reasonable?