# Way to keep track of all the questions and answers I find important/informative

Tags: support, bookmarks, profile-page, tracking

I would like to store the questions/answers I deem important and informative within my "portfolio" on Stack Overflow.

Imagine a Stack Overflow where you can quickly peek in your portfolio to recall that awesome collection of responses related to a given class of questions.

This should not be too complicated, just another entry in the database associated with my user.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23670/can-i-bookmark-a-question-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 11):

There's a favoriting feature for questions; just click the star under the voting arrows to the left of the question.

Comment: yes, but searching inside its own favourite is a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Would be nice if I could view my favorites by tag.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/ideas-on-sorting-faves OR http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4379/sort-favorites-based-on-tags