# Favourites tag filtering

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, filtering, tag-filters

I've been using Stack Exchange for a while now and I've been missing one feature I feel it's important.

I'd like to filter all the questions for my favourite tags at once, doing a logical OR between all of them. I know this can be done manually, as stated in this post: 
[Tag filtering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/stack-overflow-tag-filtering)

But I wonder if there's a better, faster way of doing this. I feel like I'd be using it quite a lot, since most part of the times I want to answer ANY question related to ANY topic I've favourited in the past (which, at least for me, means I kinda have some expertise on it).

At the moment, I can only search for some at a time or have two or more tabs opened at a time but this is clearly not ideal plus, you have to be retyping them all the time in the search bar.

Also, there used to be an script referenced in this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4379/please-allow-users-to-sort-their-favorites-based-on-tags) that doesn't seem to be working anymore (or I can't find an up-to-date one).

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: That script is now available via [SO-Family Quick-Reference to Q's, A's, and Fav's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7739)

Comment: I wish there was a in the box solution for this...